# selecting random rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of records in TSQL query.
Now I am in a certain situation where I want to select random 5 rows from output result.

Here is a snapshot of result-

[image]

Now if you see from image I have many rows coming according to this query that i've written-

```
declare @table1 table
    (
    cnt bigint,
    vid bigint
    )
    insert into @table1(cnt,vid) select count(video_id)as counts,video_views.video_id from video_views where video_views.is_active='True' group by video_views.video_id 
    select videos.*,vid from @table1 
    left join videos on videos.video_id=vid
    where cnt< '100' order by cnt desc
```

**In query-**
I am managing a video site, Where I want to implement a section where videos with low views would come.
Here in this query this table is `Videos`, Now whenever a video is viewed its view lists a row in table `video_views`.
I have written this query in manner where only records those have views less than `100` would come by descending order.

As you can see my result shows me many records where views are less than `100`. Now I wanted to select random 5 rows from this list.

How should I be approaching it to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way in SQL Server is to use `order by newid()`:

```
select top 5 videos.*, vid
from @table1 left join
     videos
     on videos.video_id=vid
where cnt < 100
order by newid() desc ;
```

There are alternatives if performance is an issue.

Note:  you should use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Don't use single quotes for an integer constant such as `100`.

Comment: This is great. What if I want to select specific numbers of random rows?

Comment: @Manoz . . . Use `top 5`.